# How to categorize a text column based on frequencies

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I have a list of citie names Which I want to categorize based on their frequencies. I first wanted to to use binning, but as this required monotone spacing I gave up on that. A next, maybe even better, approach would be create categories based on quantiles based on the frequencies using pandas.qcut. But having the quantiles, I have no idea how to create an additional column based on their quantile. Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)
cities = np.random.choice(['Ontario', 'Ottawa', 'Vancouver','Edmonton',
                           'Winnipeg', 'Churchill'], 500)
# Create fake data and their frequencies
df = pd.DataFrame (cities, columns=['City'])
freq = df['City'].value_counts()
print (freq)
# Create quantiles
qc = pd.qcut (freq, 3)
print (qc)
# And now? I have the quantiles but how to assign a categorie to each City?
category_for_each_city = df['City'] in qc # does not work, but many other things neither
```

I tried many things but none of it worked. I should be able to write a loop for this but I cannot imagine that's the Python way. I tried looking for some sklearn Transformers but could not find any with this specific solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Additionally, I have many skewed distributions, a solution that can be extended to for example a log transformation would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there...

```
In [106]: category_for_each_city = df['City'].map(qc)

In [107]: category_for_each_city
Out[107]:
0      (77.333, 84.667]
1      (72.999, 77.333]
2       (84.667, 100.0]
3       (84.667, 100.0]
4       (84.667, 100.0]
5       (84.667, 100.0]
6      (77.333, 84.667]
             ...
493     (84.667, 100.0]
494    (72.999, 77.333]
495    (77.333, 84.667]
496     (84.667, 100.0]
497    (77.333, 84.667]
498    (77.333, 84.667]
499    (77.333, 84.667]
Name: City, Length: 500, dtype: category
Categories (3, interval[float64]): [(72.999, 77.333] < (77.333, 84.667] < (84.667, 100.0]]
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [114]: qc = pd.qcut (freq, 3, labels=[0,1,2])

In [115]: category_for_each_city = df['City'].map(qc)

In [116]: category_for_each_city
Out[116]:
0      1
1      0
2      2
3      2
4      2
5      2
6      1
      ..
493    2
494    0
495    1
496    2
497    1
498    1
499    1
Name: City, Length: 500, dtype: category
Categories (3, int64): [0 < 1 < 2]
```

Comment: This is easy indeed. I was trying something like `qc.category_for_each_city.codes[df['City']]` but your solution is much simpler. Thanks a lot for your help!